# Use a table multiple times in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm making the following SQL call:

```
SELECT dpt_id, 
dpt_title, 
dpt_active, 
dpt_parent
FROM tbl_department ORDER BY dpt_title
```

where `dpt_parent` is an integer value of a parent department id (the `dpt_id` of another department).

I'd like the result set of the above call to include the dpt_title of that dpt_parent. My initial attempt at this was as follows:

```
SELECT dpt_id, 
dpt_title, 
dpt_active, 
dpt_parent, 
    (SELECT dpt_title 
     FROM tbl_department 
     WHERE tbl_department.dpt_id = dpt_parent
     ) AS parent_title
FROM tbl_department ORDER BY dpt_title
```

With the call in this form, all values of parent_title are NULL
I can see using the same table like this is confusing, what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a table alias:

```
SELECT dpt_id, 
x.dpt_title, 
x.dpt_active, 
x.dpt_parent, 
    (SELECT dpt_title 
     FROM tbl_department 
     WHERE tbl_department.dpt_id = x.dpt_parent
     ) AS parent_title
FROM tbl_department x ORDER BY dpt_title
```

but you'd be better off removing the sub select and just joining like:

```
SELECT 
     a.dpt_id
    ,a.dpt_title
    ,a.dpt_active
    ,a.dpt_parent
    ,b.dpt_title parent_title
FROM tbl_department      a
LEFT JOIN tbl_department b ON a.dpt_parent = b.dpt_id
ORDER BY a.dpt_title, b.dpt_title
```

Comment: Nested queries are dangerous for performance, the query analyzer doesn't always "see" that it can perform a JOIN. An explicit JOIN is better here.

Comment: @Lucero, the first code example if the OP's but changed so it will work, the second example is how it should be written.

Comment: @KM, I agree, but I commented before you actually added the second example. All good now ;)

Comment: This answer has both options, and some useful comments. Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT d.dpt_id, 
d.dpt_title, 
d.dpt_active, 
d.dpt_parent,
p.dpt_title parent_title
FROM tbl_department d
LEFT JOIN tbl_department p ON d.dpt_parent = p.dpt_id
ORDER BY d.dpt_title
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.dpt_id, 
d.dpt_title, 
d.dpt_active, 
d.dpt_parent,
p.dpt_title AS parent_title
FROM tbl_department d
LEFT JOIN tbl_department p
    ON p.dpt_parent = d.dpt_id
ORDER BY d.dpt_title
```

Comment: The column names in the select are ambiguous, you need to use the alias on all of them.

Comment: @Lucero, thanks, you are right. I forgot change them. Query updated.

Comment: that was why you beat me by 10 seconds in the first place... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me this query needs to be rewritten as:

```
SELECT dpt_id,  
dpt_title,  
dpt_active,  
dpt_parent,  
    (SELECT dpt_title  
     FROM tbl_department AS [dept2]
     WHERE [dept2].dpt_id = [dept1].dpt_parent 
     ) AS parent_title 
FROM tbl_department AS [dept1] ORDER BY dpt_title
```

Otherwise SQL-server will not know with instance of the table you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

i think you're looking for something like that:

```
SELECT a.dpt_id, 
a.dpt_title, 
a.dpt_active, 
a.dpt_parent, 
b.dpt_title AS parent_title
FROM tbl_department AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_department AS b ON b.dpt_id = a.dpt_parent
ORDER BY dpt_title
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to make a join on the same table or you can make a user defined function that takes the department id and return the parent department name.